# Pyinstaller - Python exe when run shows error "Failed to execute script pyi_rth_nltk"

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pyinstaller

I have developed a simple software in python with GUI. I'm actually working on Natural Language Processing and I've just put the whole NLP process in a GUI.

I tried to convert the whole project to a exe file in python using Pyinstaller. I successfully converted it to an exe file but when I run it , it shows an error message something like this
[This is the image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMqjJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved it but by using another way of converting py to exe which is the cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue earlier today and finally got it to work using the following software versions:

Python 3.6.8, nltk 3.5 and a dev version of pyinstaller:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Additionally, I used scikit-learn version 0.21.1.

Comment: @gels_yt I tried with cx_freeze, it shows this error:
attributeerror type object 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path.array' has no attribute '__redu_cython__'

...
Did you have this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: I'm not experienced at commenting in stackoverflow either. But the cx-freeze works, so thanks for the answer. As for the error of 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._shortest_path.array' has no attribute 'redu_cython' , I just added the needed packages at setup.py like you told me. Afterwards got a couple of errors for missing modules but nothing that a simple search on google can't fix (some files needed renaming).
Btw better put this option of cx-freeze as the main answer to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Few days back, I had the same problem while compressing to EXE. This Problem generally occurs when PyInstaller failes to find Libraries and Modules to import to the directory.  But I overcame this problem and the wise solution yet tedious method to do is mentioned below,

1. Convert Python Scripts to EXE with `console = True` in the `.spec` file or to be simple, do not add `--noconsole` argument while converting using System Argmuents method.(execute GUI with CMD)
2. After successfully building the file, go to respective directory (dist folder) and open command prompt
3. Run the Exe file using Command Prompt.
4. Find the error message and rectify it correspondingly. For example, consider the following Error Message, `vcomp140.dll` is missing from `\\sklearn\\libs` directory.
5. At the end of this Error Message, you'll find `Failed to load dynlib/dll` , Therefore, find the file or program which is missing. Say, Here we've `.libs\\vcomp140.dll`
6. Find `vcomp140.dll` using window search bar in your C Drive.
7. Copy the specific file and paste in the directory(under "dist" folder) where the file is missing. Here, the directory is `dist\\PyScriptToEXE\\sklearn\\.libs`

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
...
py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 169, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\MOHAMM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI38242\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[13968] Failed to execute script try
```

8. Follow the steps again using CMD to eliminate each error.